# R unnest how to avoid duplicated rows

Tags: r, unnest

I am using unnest to avoid that when I am using str_extract_all the word character(0) comes up, so far is working but unnest is giving me duplicated rows. Here is my dataframe

```
V1             
E_R4B, E_Y6A, U_5T
A_R4B, B_Y6A, U_5T
```

```
x = x %>% 
dplyr::mutate(V2 = stringr::str_extract_all(x$V2, "E_([A-Z][0-9])[A-Z]")) %>% 
  unnest(V2, keep_empty = TRUE)
```

Output

```
V1                  V2
E_R4B, E_Y6A, U_5T  E_R4B
E_R4B, E_Y6A, U_5T  E_Y6A
A_R4B, B_Y6A, U_5T  NA
```

My desired output is

```
V1                  V2
E_R4B, E_Y6A, U_5T  E_R4B,E_Y6A
A_R4B, B_Y6A, U_5T  NA
```

If I don't use unnest I get characther(0), which has been impossible to delete, and unnest is my only way to overcome the issue but I really wat to have only 1 row.

```
V1                  V2
E_R4B, E_Y6A, U_5T  E_R4B,E_Y6A
A_R4B, B_Y6A, U_5T  characther(0)
```

Another thing I tried was:

```
x$V2 = str_extract_all(x$V1, "E_([A-Z][0-9])[A-Z]",simplify = T)
```

It works but then I get

```
V1                  V2[,1]  V2[,2]
E_R4B, E_Y6A, U_5T  E_R4B   E_Y6A
A_R4B, B_Y6A, U_5T  NA      NA
```

Which I am happy with but then I have issues with the function paste, because at the end I want V3
MY IDEAL OUTPUT

```
V1                      V2      V2       V3
E_R4B, E_Y6A, U_5T      E_R4B   E_Y6A    E_R4B,E_Y6A
A_R4B, B_Y6A, U_5T      NA      NA
```

Comment: Can you use `dput` to show the example data so as to get the structure correctly

Comment: sorry I am very new dont know what is dput

Answer (score 0):

If we want a single string, then `paste` the output

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
x <- x %>% 
  mutate(v2 = map_chr(str_extract_all(V1, '\\bE_([A-Z][0-9][A-Z])'), toString))
```

If we want multiple columns, use `unnest_wider`

```
library(tidyr)
x <-  x %>%
   mutate(v2 = str_extract_all(V1, '\\bE_([A-Z][0-9][A-Z])')) %>% 
   unnest_wider(v2)
```

Comment: seems like is doing it but it shows is as a tibble on the R console and when I open the dataframe x is like did not write it in there.

Comment: I guess is working sorry one moment I am super new

Comment: @Nnnz that is just assignment i.e. `x <- x %>%...` i.e. if you don't assign, it won't automatically modify the object